# Overriding equals method and unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This is first attempt at unit testing.  My `.Equals` method is failing on `TestSet_Equals_True`, `TestSet_Equals_True_Shuffled_Order`.  Hoping for clarification as to whether this is a problem with HOW I Unit test or something is wrong with my `.Equals` method.

**Unit Test:**

```
private void Populate(Set set, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        set.Add(i);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSet_Equals_True()
{
    Set set1 = new Set();
    Set set2 = new Set();

    Populate(set1, POPULATE_COUNT);
    Populate(set2, POPULATE_COUNT);
    bool expected = true;
    bool actual = set1.Equals(set2);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

**Class:**

```
List<object> _set;

//Override Equals
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
    return false;
Set o = (Set)obj;

if (this._set.Count != o._set.Count)
    return false;

o._set.Sort();
this._set.Sort();

return _set.Equals(o._set); }
```

Comment: What exactly is failing?

Comment: "TestSet_Equals_True", "TestSet_Equals_True_Shuffled_Order"  Should be adding identical elements and testing true if the elements are tested for equality, and true if they are out of order but still same elements.

Comment: Have you also overriden `GetHashCode`? Also, have a look at this article - it describes a solution for array comparison:http://www.dotnetperls.com/sequenceequal

Comment: @JoannaTurban: Yes overriden the GetHashCode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` implementation of Equals is the default implementation of `object.Equals` - Reference Equality.

To see if two `IEnumerable<T>` are equal, You can use the extension method `IEnumerable<T>.SequenceEquals` - Don't forget to add `using` statement for `System.Linq` namespace.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't sort your set inside an equal method. The `Equals` should not change your object in any way. It should only determine if 2 objects are identical.

You could use `SequenceEquals` but do realize that `SequenceEquals` does not handle `NullReferenceExceptions`.

So I think the problem is in your Equals implementation. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var isEqual = false;

        var otherSet = obj as Set;

        if (otherSet != null)
        {
            isEqual = _set.Count == otherSet.Count;
            isEqual &= _set.SequenceEqual(otherSet);
        }

        return isEqual;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Sort` calls in your `Equals`. I don't know what purpose they serve and they should NOT be in an `Equals` implementation. List `Equals` just does reference equality. You can use the `SequenceEquals` extension method to `IEnumerable<T>` to check equality here:

```
var a = new List<int> {1, 2};
var b = new List<int> {1, 2};

Assert.False(a.Equals(b));
Assert.True(a.SequenceEqual(b));
```